# What ie-specific CSS do I need to add to my Wordpress site to fix this issue?

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer, compatibility

Here is how the site looks on Internet Explorer: 
http://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/0c3c039e85f44bb70fddfc34b887b5bbc3357899

I've only seen it on the latest version of IE on Windows 8.1, but it's possible that it happens on older versions as well. Unfortunately, I'm on a Mac and can't find any emulators to run IE.. So I am coming to the greatest community of tech-savvy people I know of for help.

The site (built with Wordpress) is [commercialpaintersinc.com](http://commercialpaintersinc.com). It looks great on Google Chrome and Safari.. so this issue seems to be just in IE (although I haven't tested in Firefox either..).

This is how it is supposed to look:
[image]

Anyone got any idea as to what CSS I entered that caused the issue and/or how I can fix it to make it look how it is supposed to on ALL browsers?

Any feedback is majorly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can install a free virtual machine from Microsoft to run IE on your Mac. https://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads

Comment: Or try the free trial of browserstack.com which emulates for you via flash.

Comment: FYI: The problem you're having with IE also applies to Firefox 33 - looks the same on both browsers.

Comment: @SteveSanders / Kai, or you can *stream* IE to your Mac using http://remote.modern.ie ;)

Comment: My bet is the you have a typo or malformed HTML. Sometimes Chrome will correct it for you. Try running everything through a linter/syntax checker.

Comment: Thanks, guys. I was only finding emulators that I had to pay for or that were only giving me screenshots. I don't have the cash to pay for anything right now which is why I came here. I will use Firefox first and then download the Microsoft emulator if the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

You are presently using negative margins to adjust layout, which is giving wildly different results in all three major rendering engines (Trident, Blink, and Gecko). I would advise against this, as it's likely these vendors will need to discuss whose approach is correct, or if all three need to adjust to be in better conformance with a fourth alternative.

The primary issue is is the over-hang of your logo beyond your negative margin. If you were to position the image absolutely, you could get more consistent results. However, upon doing so you will need to restore the layout of your header since a crucial element will no longer contribute to its dimensions.

```css
#logo {
    position: absolute;
}

#main-header {
    min-height: 160px;
}
```

The above two rules appear to restore the layout for me in IE, and Firefox. That being said, I still think Chrome may be in the wrong here - you should always test your layout regularly in all three major browsers to ensure you aren't building on top of a browser bug.

I work on the Internet Explorer team, and have filed an issue internally for us to investigate this particular layout anomaly further. I've created a [reduced demo of the issue as a public fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/hwwu4oLd/show/) as well.

If you need to test Internet Explorer from a Mac in the future, please visit http://modern.ie.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the help. I was having a mental blockage and once again this community helped me to move forward.

Jonathan Sampson was correct that the root cause was that the CSS was not originally done correctly. I did the CSS edits myself and I am self-taught, so this was no surprise to me, haha. However, I had already come up with a solution.

My Solution:

I used the famous CSS Browser Selector script which can be found here: http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector

I added it to my JS folder (mysite.com/wp-includes/js/css_browser_selector.js) and then added:
`<script src="css_browser_selector.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`
right before the `</head>` tag in the header.php file.

At that point I was able to just create browser-specific CSS. It's dumb that FF and IE are so picky when it originally worked fine how I had it in both Chrome and Safari... But oh well.

Here is the code for Chrome/Safari vs. the code for Firefox/IE:

Chrome/Safari (Webkit):

```
.webkit #logo {
margin-bottom: 10px;
max-height: 110px;
position: relative;
z-index: 99999;
background: #fff;
border-radius: 150px;
border: 20px solid #fff;
}
.webkit #main-header {
padding: 10px 0 0 0;
margin-bottom: -65px;
margin-top: -20px;
}
```

Firefox (and same used for IE as well):

```
.gecko .et_pb_slider {
top: -60px;
margin-bottom: -63px;
}
.gecko #logo {
margin-bottom: 10px;
max-height: 110px;
position: relative;
z-index: 99999 !important;
background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #FFF;
border: 20px solid #FFF !important;
border-radius: 150px;
}
.gecko #main-header {
margin-top: -20px;
}
```

So yeah I didn't see Jon's answer until after I had "fixed" the issue. So, I will leave it as is.. although I'm sure my CSS is very sloppy! :P

Screenshot of IE browser now that it is fixed:
http://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/0d669a15d18040086fede2df90f134e526aef8f3

Thanks,
Chris